# Java Errors: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: java, cmd, char

I am running a Program in CMD.

I am using 2 methods to have it print out like the below:

**Print all characters between a and w: 

a b c d e f g h i j 

k l m n o p q s t 

u v w**

Below is what I have so far ... But I can not get past here.
I keep getting all sorts of errors.

```
public class Letters{
public static void main (String[] args) {
System.out.println("Print all characters between a and w");

for (char i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
String myrow = printChars('a','w');
System.out.println(myrow);
}
}
public static void printChars (char c1, char c2){


}
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the documentation regarding for loops in Java https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html  ? Hint delete `;` right after the right parentheses of the for statement. Also, the curly braces don't match

Comment: If you want help, it is not enough to say "all sorts of errors". You need to add the exact error messages, and show where in the code those errors appear.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: Unit03Lab.printRow
 at Unit03Lab.main(Unit03Lab.java:6)

Comment: 1) remove ";" at the end of "for" line, 2) move "}" from the bottom to the line above "public static void printChars" 3) replace "printRow()" with "printChars('a','w')" 4) replace "void printChars" with "String printChars" 5) add "return null" inside printChars {} brackets

Comment: @vovka i have updated my code above but i am still receiving the error.

Comment: printChar vs printChar**s**, 4 and 5 steps form previous comment, 
6) ";" at the end of String myrow line

Answer (score 1):

First of, I recommend to properly indent your code, making it easier to read. Second as you are using char you can just check against the value of the character. `char c = 'a'` like that. If you increment c it then has the value of `b`.

```
public class Letters
{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Print all characters between a and w");

        for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'w'; c++) {
            System.out.print(c);
            if ((c+1 - 'a') % 10 == 0) {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\n");

        printChars ('d','z');
    }

    public static void printChars (char c1, char c2) {
        // no valid range, can also add checks to see if they are actual letters
        if (c1 > c2) {
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Print all characters between " + c1 + " and " + c2);
        for (char c = c1; c <= c2; c++) {
            System.out.print(c);
            if ((c+1 - c1) % 10 == 0) {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This part checks what iteration is currently being done, it then checks if that iteration is divisible by 10, to add a new line, if not, move along.

```
if ((c+1 - 'a') % 10 == 0) {
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: THANKS! I see I had a couple o.incorrect things going on. But the program is not outputting the letters in rows.. @emz

Comment: Care to clarify? It does print every letter on a new line, from the `System.out.println();` and it is in order from just incrementing once every iteration.

Comment: 10 letters per line @emz

Comment: Oh `abcdefghij` then a new line and `klmnopqrst` on the second? A hint of what to use is `- 'a';` will give you which index you are working on. For the `printChars (...)` you can use `- c1;` to accomplish the same. I will leave that exercise to you for now. If you run into further problems don't hesitate to give a poke. But please do try first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90708/discussion-between-babar-miamor-and-emz).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    char c1='a';
    char c2='w';

    String str= "a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q s t u v w";
    Pattern compile = Pattern.compile(".*"+c1+"(.*)"+c2+".*");
    Matcher matcher = compile.matcher(str);
    boolean found = matcher.find();
    System.out.println("found:"+ found);
    if (found) System.out.println(matcher.group(1));

}
```

Comment: (a) Code only answers are low quality. Please add an explanation. (b) This is hard coded - the OP seems to want to do it flexibly.

Answer (score 0):

E:\Java>jdk1.8.0_111\bin>java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0.jar -htmlsuite " *firefox "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" " https://www.google.com/" "E:\Selenium\newsuite.html" "E:\Selenium\result.html"

i got the above mentioned error.please help